# Trying to run usersetup and it's running as an admin even though im not. I've already tried to un check the box compatibility settings

Tags: visual-studio-code

i was trying to reinstall vs code, and when i tried to run the setup up this popped up.

[what popped up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0IvdE.png)

i've tried to reinstall the user setup but that didnt work, i also went to propriety and unchecked the run in admin box and that didnt do anything i did it for ever user too. None of those things worked

Comment: Welcome! Can you please read about [the problems with images of text](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/11107541) and then [edit] to **add transcriptions** of your images of text as actual text? Perhaps useful: [/help/formatting](/help/formatting).